# newbie question - postfix and s-mail - ""Can't canonicalize""

Tags: postfix

just making my very first steps with mail on Ubuntu. Followed [This guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But when I try to initialise my mailbox with

```
echo 'init' | mail -s 'init' -Snorecord sammy
```

I get the "would be" expected response

```
Can't canonicalize "/home/user/Maildir
```

However, once I do

```
ls -R ~/Maildir
```

I get nothing in response. I.e. my maildir  is not being created and Maildir not initialised.

What to look for? How can I troubleshoot/debug this?

Comment: have you managed to fix it? I'm suck there too ...

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same issue but fixed this by doing the following:

1. opening my postfix `main.cf` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

and adding the following to the end of the file:

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

and restarting postfix.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

At that point running

```
echo 'init' | mail -s 'init' -Snorecord my_username
```

returned

```
Can't canonicalize "/home/my_username/Maildir"
```

but when I ran

```
ls -R ~/Maildir
```

The mail directory was there!! Success!!

Apparently, when you change parameter home_mailbox in postfix, you need to adjust the configuration so it will search mail in new location. With home_mailbox = Maildir/, postfix will store the email in Maildir directory relative with user home directory.

Hope this helps future mail pioneers.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem, and after messing around with Google, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468109/postfix-unable-to-find-etc-postfix-virtual-file).

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
$ sudo service postfix reload
```

Solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method posted earlier.
The Directory error is gone but still not getting mail.
[mail(1) isn't able to open Maildir mailbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47688/mail1-isnt-able-to-open-maildir-mailbox)

*Update 1*: I tried creating a new user after this, and it seemed to work. The files are showing up. Maybe it is a permissions issue. If I figure it out, I'll update this post.

*Update 2:*
Recreate these commands ([Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto)) and post what you see.

> Install mailx package for use as command mail utility program. Mail
>   command is installed with this package.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install mailutils
> ```
>
> Add a user before you start this.
>
> ```
> sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash fmaster
> sudo passwd fmaster
> ```
>
> Test your default installation using the following code segment.
>
> ```
> telnet localhost 25
> ```
>
> (if that doesn't work, check to see if postfix is running)
>
> ```
> sudo postfix status
> ```
>
> If it is not running, start it
>
> ```
> sudo postfix start
> ```
>
> Postfix will prompt like following in the terminal so that you can use
>   to type SMTP commands.
>
> ```
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> Connected to mail.fossedu.org.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> 220 localhost.localdomain ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
> ```
>
> Type the following code segment in Postfix's prompt.
>
> ```
> ehlo localhost
> mail from: root@localhost
> rcpt to: fmaster@localhost
> data
> Subject: My first mail on Postfix
>
> Hi,
> Are you there?
> regards,
> Admin
> .  # (Type the .[dot] in a new Line and press Enter )
> quit
> ```
>
> Check the mailbox of fmaster
>
> ```
> su - fmaster
> mail
> ```
>
> When you type mail command an output like follows display in your
>   terminal.
>
> ```
> Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
> "**/var/mail/fmaster**": 2 messages 2 new
> >N  1 root@localhost     Mon Mar  6 12:49   13/479   Just a test
>  N  2 root@localhost     Mon Mar  6 12:51   15/487   My first mail
> &
> ```
>
> If you see the following line: `/var/mail/fmaster` type:
>
> ```
> sudo postconf -e "home_mailbox = Maildir/"
> ```

Repeat steps and see that your folder has changed to `/home/fmaster/Maildir`

Answer (score 0):

in this code:

```
echo 'init' | mail -s 'init' -Snorecord sammy
```

try:

```
echo 'init' | mail -s 'init' -snorecord sammy
```

I tried to change the uppercase -S to lowercase -s