# How to download a specific IMAP folder to mbox from Gmail with Thunderbird?

Tags: command-line, email, mailutils, mbox, maildir

Looking to [export](https://askubuntu.com/q/26308/847449) mails from `Thunderbird` and verify that the emails are readable from the console:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ mail -f linux.mbox 
Cannot create mailbox linux.mbox: Requested item not found
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ head linux.mbox 
From boris.gjenero@gmail.com Sun, 08 Oct 2023 04:18:08
Delivered-To: saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a05:7208:81cd:b0:74:9338:9721 with SMTP id l13csp1184940rbf;
        Sat, 7 Oct 2023 21:18:15 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6870:5386:b0:1d7:b3b4:4b8d with SMTP id h6-20020a056870538600b001d7b3b44b8dmr4448288oan.0.1696738695055;
        Sat, 07 Oct 2023 21:18:15 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1696738695; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=mM9qT5ZWLbKeuGpRGsMnV8phEqDH2EAu82fPqpCIKm+dstFXHfTesv7yiAL1PKchHt
         ctGMOVXc99GhL9Eh71jLGEk2BCVrwBtiQGYyPW5yZVC9WxvprQDJ9gpNED4L/pZtvshQ
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ tail linux.mbox 
quot;Android-x86&quot; group.<br />
To unsubscribe from this group and stop receiving emails from it, send an e=
mail to <a href=3D"mailto:android-x86+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com">android=
-x86+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com</a>.<br />
To view this discussion on the web visit <a href=3D"https://groups.google.c=
om/d/msgid/android-x86/314ca2d0-f910-4cde-9deb-449ab3aa3df5%40gmail.com?utm=
_medium=3Demail&utm_source=3Dfooter">https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/andr=
oid-x86/314ca2d0-f910-4cde-9deb-449ab3aa3df5%40gmail.com</a>.<br />

--------------NtsjPZDcs2AOcGZwtJdN5gK3--
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$ wc -l linux.mbox 
2425 linux.mbox
nicholas@mordor:~/Downloads$
```

However, not seemingly able to [open](https://askubuntu.com/q/1494140/847449) the files with the `mail` command.

I'm selecting the [option](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/) to download as `mbox`.

How is it confirmed that the messages are downloaded as `mbox` which can be opened by `mailutils`?

This is over IMAP with Gmail.